# Custom taxonomy "hierarchical' => true" not working in WordPress 2.8

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Another WordPress issue from me!

I've been trying to set up two custom taxonomies in WordPress 2.8 for "Course subject" and "Type of opportunity".

I used this code in functions.php:

```
function create_pc_db_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy( 'course', 'post', array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'label' => __('Course subject', 'series'),
        'query_var' => 'course',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'courses' )
    ) );

    register_taxonomy( 'type', 'post', array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'label' => __('Type of opportunity', 'series'),
        'query_var' => 'type',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'types' )
    ) );
}
```

which works absolutely fine, but I want hierarchical (category-style) admin boxes rather than tag-style admin boxes.

However, when I set `'hierarchical' => true` so that the above code becomes:

```
function create_pc_db_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy( 'course', 'post', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => __('Course subject', 'series'),
        'query_var' => 'course',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'courses' )
    ) );

    register_taxonomy( 'type', 'post', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => __('Type of opportunity', 'series'),
        'query_var' => 'type',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'types' )
    ) );
}
```

I get no boxes at all.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's working but there isn't any admin UI automatically built in WP-Admin, according to [Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10122) "Support will be added later"

Comment: so there is admin UI for tag-style but not for hierarchy-style?

Comment: Annoyingly yes, however this doesn't meant that you can't build one yourself, it just means that it doesn't automatically happen.